# Cannot open mapped network drive file PHP

Tags: php, windows, file-exists, network-drive, mapped-drive

I am trying to load a file from a mapped network drive on Windows Server 2008. The mapped drive is `S:\` and the file is `conqueror.mdb`. I am using the IP address I am seeing in File Explorer but it still says it cannot find the file.

```
$dbName = "\\xx.xx.xxx.xx\S:\conqueror.mdb";

if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
    die("Could not find database file.");
}


$conn = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=pass;");
```

Comment: Use single quotes instead of double quotes for `$dbName` assignment.

Comment: I tried that and still get the same error.

Comment: Can you access that file from the Command Prompt?

Comment: I don't use Windows, but if `S:` is mapped to the network drive, why do you need to put `\\xx.xx.xxx.xx` before it? Can't you just write `S:`?

Comment: Note that Mapped Network drives are only per-user, not systemwide. If your PHP process is running under a different user-account compared to your local desktop account (which they usually are, such as `NETWORK SERVICE` or as a dedicated IIS Application Pool process) then the driver mappings will not be available.

Comment: I've tried it with just `S:` but the same thing. I am pretty sure it's the issue @Dai suggested.